# How do I fetch this in Laravel Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have structure like this how do I fetch this and display in table:

[image: data]

Here is my code:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
   var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref("Accounts");
   firebaseRef.on( "value" , function(snapshot){
       snapshot.forEach(function(element){
        console.log(element.val() );
        
       });
   })
```